# What does Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am troubleshooting an issue of removing a user from a SharePoint list that does not exist in the Active Directory anymore.

However, an error occurred at the following statement.

```
foreach (var requestUser in requestUsers)
{
    var item = requestUserList.Items.Add();
    bool allowUnsafeUpdate = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
    try
    {
        if (!allowUnsafeUpdate)
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        }

        try
        {
            //statement below is displayed as <Target Audience Receiver|ItemAdded> 
            //in log file

            requestUser.User = web.EnsureUser(requestUser.LoginId);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //statement below is displayed as <Target Audience Receiver|ItemAdded> 
            //in log file

            requestUser.User = web.SiteUsers[requestUser.LoginId];
        }
    }

    finally
    {
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdate; <--ERROR HIT HERE
    }
```

May I know what does `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdate;` do?

It has already set `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;` in the `if` statement at the beginning.

So I am not sure what does the statement `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdate;` does, as my logging got stopped here with the following error.

I appreciate if someone can explain the following statement to me, on what it does.

> web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdate;

[image]

Comment: What is `web`? Can you post the code where you define it?

Comment: web is the variable storing my SP site,

Comment: If the web is storing the SPSite, change it to be named site, then the SPWeb varialbe (if used) can be correctly named web

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AllowUnsafeUpdates is set to true when you are trying to update the database as a result of the GET request.

Say you have a list and you want to update something, then you need to set AllowUnsafeUpdates = true for the web and after you have done you need to set it back to false.

AllowUnsafeUpdates = false protects from cross site scripting.

So if you need to allow your code to make some updates, you need to set allow unsafe updates to true and then back to false as soon you update.

Take a look here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms478070(v=office.15)

Comment: Thanks. I understand that `AllowUnsafeUpdates` allow user to update a SP item, such as `item.Update()`. However, would you mind explaining what does `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdate;` does? Does it set it to `true`, `false`, or others. I see that it may be getting the truefalse value and setting it into the variable `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates`, and not the executing of update itself...

Comment: It is setting the flag back to its previous state

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!allowUnsafeUpdate)
{
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
}
```

First, you are checking if allowUnsafeUpdate is false, then you are setting it to true so that you can make your changes.

```
finally
{
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdate;
}
```

When you are done making changes, you are setting it back to its original value. Whatever it was when this method received the call.